# Python performance with temporary variable

Tags: python, performance

I don't know if the following two snippets have same performance.

Code1:

```
for fid1 in FId1:
    if fid1 in [i['FId'] for i in entity['F']]:
        res.append([intId1,fid1,entity['Id'],intId2])
```

Code2:

```
 temp = [i['FId'] for i in entity['F']]
 tempid = entity['Id']
 for fid1 in FId1:
        if fid1 in temp:
            res.append([intId1,fid1,tempid,intId2])
```

Basically, in the loop I don't change the entity.

I think in Code1, without optimization, it would generate that list in every loop. Although it is more readable, would that one be slower?

And therefore I try to store the temp, so that the list would be generated only once.

Performance is quite important for this task...

Comment: Have you profiled them yet?

Comment: You'll also want to make `temp` a `set` (assuming `i['FId']` is hashable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes exactly, the first code will generate the temp list for every iterations. This is true for CPython (the native Python interpreter). Technically, the optimization you used in Code 2 is called [precomputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomputation).

However, if you use an optimizer like PyPy, it might be different as it can maybe detect for this instance that your list never changes, and thus store it as a constant.

Answer (score 2):

When performance matters, measure it.

If you don't measure performance, you don't know what performance you are achieving.  And more importantly, you won't know if that performance is improved or made worse by future changes.

Answer (score 2):

Not only create that list outside of loop, change it to set (or frozenset if it's constant) - you'll experience `O(1)` membership test time.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('123456 in s', setup='s = frozenset(xrange(1000000))', number=1000)
7.14463625257622e-05
>>> timeit.timeit('123456 in l', setup='l = list(xrange(1000000))', number=1000)
2.899147340951913
```